# create relationship in parse dashboard

Tags: ios, parse-platform

does anyone know if it is possible to create relationships in the dashboard of parse?

I'm running the bitnami parse api 1.0.18 through aws ec2 and can't see anyway of doing it and the documentations only says you can do it through code.  i want to have these set up in the background as the user won't write to them, probably just download some data and images.

i could just go and create a whole heap of tables with unique identifiers but this seems a bit of a dumb work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest you look into Cloud code. This is one of the reason why cloud code works so well! Simple to setup and little bit of javascript you'll be on your way.

http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/cloudcode/guide/

If its something that needs to happen before the insert, look at the `beforeSave` method.